# Customer Profile Transaction List returns "No Records Found" for Subscriptions

Tags: authorize.net

I'm using Authorize.Net and trying to get a list of transactions made for a given recurring billing subscription customer.

I can call `ARBGetSubscriptionListRequest` to get a list of all my subscribers which shows the customer's `subscriptionId` and the `customerProfileId`.

I can pass that `subscriptionId` to `ARBGetSubscriptionRequest` to view data about the subscription, this also includes the `customerProfileId`.

But when I pass that `customerProfileId` to `getTransactionListForCustomerRequest` it always returns `{"code":"I00004","text":"No records found."}`

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? or a better way to get a list of previous payments made by a recurring subscription customer?  Thanks!

EDIT: looking at user comments in this thread (https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Enhanced-Customer-Profile-Reporting-New-Webhooks-UI/ba-p/57375) it would appear that the "GetTransactionListForCustomer" reporting does NOT include transactions made for subscription based customers at this time.  This is disappointing.

Does anyone know another way to get a historical list of transactions for a given subscription?